# how to enable redmine (ruby on rails) logging?

Tags: installation, logging, ruby, ruby-on-rails, redmine

For some reason my RedMine install never gets any log files.

Redmine is an open source project management system written with Ruby on Rails.

I'm a total newbie to Ruby or Rails.

Have searched the wiki, forums, tickets without any clue to this seemingly simply thing.

By the way, this was an upgrade from a previous version on this TurnKey Linux Application. I can see that the backup folder of the older version has a log file with lots of log messages.

But mine in /var/www/railsapp/log/production.log has only one line from several days ago announcing the the log is created.

Now, my real problem is some strangeness that started happening in the application but I feel that that A) See the logs, I might realized it was something I changed in my configuration (mucking with VMs and network setup)  B) will have the logs to post in an issue to the redmine team.

Meanwhile, I can't even get anything to log. Is there a debug level to set?

Sincerely,
Wayne

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was permissions related. After putzing around I got it working just by getting the owner and group of the files to match the user running the railsapp and proper read/write permission. Just confusing how it ever got broken. - Wayne

Answer (score 3):

I've not done much with Rails either, but I'd take a look in `config/environments/production.rb` to see what options there are for logging.  Logging is usually done with the Logger standard ruby library which should just generate a log based on your current environment (eg log/production.log).  You will get more events logged if you aren't in the production environment - production only logs info or above wheras other environments logs everything including debug.  If you're getting exceptions in the application then take a look at [Exceptional](http://getexceptional.com/) or [New Relic](http://www.newrelic.com/).